# Flattening List of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a different case of list Flattening.

Suppose I have a list of list ,say `l=[['a'],[['p','l']]]` . I simply want `['a',['p','l']]`. That is the single elements should not be in nested lists and the lists having more than one element can be nested twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this

```
In [4]: l=[['a'],[['p','l']]]

In [5]: [j for i in l for j in i]
Out[5]: ['a', ['p', 'l']]
```